# Extension of a non-stable two-dimensional vector bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a Riemann surface and $V$ a two-dimensional holomorphic vector bundle over $M$. On this [paper](https://watermark.silverchair.com/s3-55-1-59.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAoYwggKCBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggJzMIICbwIBADCCAmgGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMEyf-HvhVyqGfNTtgAgEQgIICOd6O4lwhNWYH6thdw0yp0gLZpZsw5uHIo8KxljRtb4SQ-tC8AS--1e_zmmEDM_aD7-GwIfj4aow8QZGVV6LgoFPFpQca4663AlTNZrLP5Hvu_1GjOvpUfbz12oiN_1PnxachJAEnXVsTQTmMsZRtkZXWUT1m0wBt8l-UdOw-NCG_2lBXeiy6sYAwLHeQwPff-T5rqbiTPMx-Ee_8R8OU3Ms14FtXDBEGDc9ICmF5pH8D5WL36nHuoHbS30LL5bGiwbRtdmYm7Y7LFDt1zp2Osg2jr6L3We4s77qPDd_hj_ezxYPx-rSLRY0FAK9eUsF2IkSyOMFFGyl1z-3O_zyPEWi44JYy8xLjCXh41uJq71qs9Zd5BqEg1y44tE0Sh9T7y_Wr8I6orB6Dy001J1UArFywD1Qcvpbbn06rTlx6HcQlxRqsRo_5YRewXrgm36xJWqc2Rt9yZiJmEBXi1B2lYC9vkjYeu3fFsj3d93OA9ugeTn8LWMIV9AN41jVC70fHsAaEq224-6NlCWB1QexwHK1o1CpKE2b2Qv7pGwEWc6FG0CbPexu2D9eOv55tk3RnrMhLu1e5QKxnoZ9K2TOCHfyWSIE7GEbEliOYZcPoumS1Fij0JgAHKCePJOVF8zuqdYwEwsVC7SYGv4_9VKB2Dx1QI3ygU0B4TkiId9iaiZfJmtleRLs97td-i0ZVbYMR9nu282mOl7pvXdzU5KEEz8WjJGPdH9zmv160AOTSOOYWWqrS7zmDWWsW) (page 72), the author states that if $V$ has a subbundle $L$ with $\deg L \geq \frac{1}{2}\deg\wedge^{2}V$, then $V$ is an extension
$$
0\rightarrow L \rightarrow V \rightarrow L^{*}\otimes  \wedge^{2}V \rightarrow 0
$$

Does anyone know how can I construct the map from $V$ to $L^{*}\otimes  \wedge^{2}V$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take the quotient $V/L$ and note that since its rank is 1, one has
$$
V/L \cong \det(V/L) \cong \det(V) \otimes \det(L)^{-1} \cong \wedge^2V \otimes L^*.
$$